# replace a string containing an unknown number with sed

Tags: sed

Using sed to I would like to edit a number without knowing how many digits it is.

```
EX1. 
variableA = 34, variableB = 4

EX2.
variableA = 123, variableB = 22
```

I would like to be able to update either of these variables without knowing what the original number is. The format of the line will not change but the number values will.

Ideally this would be a s// expression to replace the number assignment

Comment: Are you looking for a `s//` expression that substitutes one number with another?

Comment: @PaulHicks Yes, that would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitution replacement with a regex will do this.  Unfortunately, then you have a problem and a regex.  But anyway: tweak these to replace 42 with your real new value; I use "," or "$" to tell the difference between the two variables:

**For variableA**:

```
sed -e 's/= [0-9]\{1,\},/= 42,/'
```

**For variableB**:

```
sed -e 's/= [0-9]\{1,\}$/= 42/'
```

Comment: Do you need more parameterization than that?

Comment: nice answer, probably a '+' instead a '*' would do a better job.

Comment: Yes it would, but not all versions of sed support it. I think my answer will work on all versions.

Comment: The POSIX-compliant equivalent of `+` in a basic regex is the somewhat clunky  `\{1,\}` (`\+`, by contrast, is a _GNU_ Sed extension).

Comment: Parentheses must be `\ `-escaped in _basic_ regular expressions; currently, they're interpreted as _literals_ in your command, so your command won't work as intended.
Given your approach, however, you don't need parentheses at all (but you should change `*` to `\{1,\}`).

Comment: The downside of using most of my sed through gvim on linux.. I forget a lot of the stuff I learned on a PDP11-70 in 1989...

Comment: It should be noted that `[0-9]+` is just syntactic sugar for `[0-9][0-9]*`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this **single-pass** solution:

```sh
n1=55 n2=66 # define replacement numbers

sed -E 's/^(.* = )[[:digit:]]+(, .* = )[[:digit:]]+$/\1'"$n1"'\2'"$n2"'/' <<EOF
variableA = 34, variableB = 4
variableA = 123, variableB = 22
EOF
```

This yields:

```
variableA = 55, variableB = 66
variableA = 55, variableB = 66
```

- Uses `-E` to enable support for *extended* regular expressions, which are both more powerful and simpler in terms of syntax - this will work on both BSD/OSX and Linux platforms.
- By matching the *entire* line, it is possible to specify *both* replacement numbers with *one* `s///` function call.
- The replacement number variables are spliced into the otherwise single-quoted Sed script.

Alternatively, a **2-pass solution** if you want to **match by variable names**:

```
n1=55 n2=66 # define replacement numbers

sed -E 's/(variableA = )[[:digit:]]+/\1'"$n1"'/; s/(variableB = )[[:digit:]]+/\1'"$n2"'/' <<EOF
variableA = 34, variableB = 4
variableA = 123, variableB = 22
EOF
```

- Two separate `s///` calls are made, one for each variable.
- This could be made more robust with respect to unambiguous name and more flexible whitespace matching, but I've left that out for brevity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex

```
echo "variableA = 123, variableB = 22" | sed -e 's/\(variableA = \)[0-9]\+, \(variableB = \)[0-9]\+/\1999,\2888/'
```

results:

```
variableA = 999,variableB = 888
```

Comment: Seems to be a lot of escaping in that expression. Is it all necessary?

Comment: @PaulHicks: Yes, parentheses must be `\ `-escaped in _basic_ regular expressions. The only potential problem is the use of non-portable _GNU_ Sed extension `\+`, which won't work in _BSD_ Sed, for instance; using `\{1,\}` would fix that.